# Return custom payload from default response

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

In Django 2.0 I am using the rest_auth and currently it returns a response like

```
{
"token": "foo_token",
"user":{
    "pk": 1,
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
    }
}
```

I would like to change this to return something besides the default response django provides. Something like...

```
{
"token": "foo_token",
"pk":1,
"username": "admin",
"somefield": "Foo Funk"
}
```

My urls.py look like this currently

```
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
url(r'^refresh-token/', refresh_jwt_token),
url(r'^api/userlist', users.user_list),
```

The only place I can find to possibly change the response is in library files which I am sure is not wise to change. Any help would be great.

Comment: Try to change serializers according to your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rest_auth` allows you to change the responses by specifying your own serializer implementation in your `settings.py`.

For example if you wanted to customize the response for JWT authentication, then you might create:

```
# myapp/serializers.py

class MyCustomJWTSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    token = serializers.CharField()
    pk = serializers.IntegerField()
    username = serializers.CharField()
    ...
```

which you can then configure in your `settings.py` as:

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'JWT_SERIALIZER': 'myapp.serializers.MyCustomJWTSerializer'
}
```

More info here: https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html